# How do you add a web app to the backend pool of Azure Application Gateway?

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

I have created a Webapp and have added an IP restriction so that it can only be accessed via the Azure Application Gateway Public IP.

In the Application Gateway, I navigated to the BackEnd Pools, clicked to ADD backend pool and copied the web app URL e.g. https://mywebapp.azurewebsites.net, it complained it only wanted FQDN so I removed the https:// and entered in mywebapp.azurewebsites.net

I then navigated to my Application Gateway and copied the public IP address of the gateway and entered it in my browser to test the app but it won't see the web app, I get the error "This site can’t be reached."

Have I missed a step, is the FQDN incorrect? Do I need to use a custom Domain?

Comment: Do you have enabled health probe or can you display any screenshots?

Comment: I havent enabled any heath probes as havent got to that bit yet? Can you advise?

Comment: Where have  you added the ip restriction in web app ?

Comment: i went to the webapp , then clicked networking and then ip restrictions
Clicked configure IP Restrictions
Clicked Add Rule
Entered a name eg- appgateway-allow
Entered the Subnet Address of the APP Gateway
IP Address left on V4
Clicked Allow
Priority - wasnt sure on this so put in 100

Answer (score 0):

One of the things I would look for is if a listener and a rule has been created. This is required to enable the application gateway to route traffic appropriately to the backend pool.

More info here -
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-web-app-powershell

I tried adding an existing app service web app to the backend pool like you mentioned and realized that it was not adding the listener/rule for it. When i used the powershell script as mentioned in the link above which creates a listener and a rule , i was able to successfully hit backend pool website when i browsed using the Application Gateway public ip/dns.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-create-gateway-arm

Comment: If I have IP restriction on and alllow only the APP Gateway to the App I  get the error " 502 - Web server received an invalid response"  When the Web server (while acting as a gateway or proxy) contacted the upstream content server, it received an invalid response from the content server." If I remove the IP Restriction which allows the App Gateway and then use the App Gateway's DNS it works! However I need to only allow access through the App Gateway but when I add the IP Restriction I get error 502?

Comment: that hasnt fixed the issue, i get 502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.